# Which Time Tracker application do you recommend?

Tags: software-recommendation

I have to do three or four jobs a day, and each has several parts. I want a time tracker tool to help me know how much time I've spent on each part and each job overall.

I've found some like `gnotime` and `hamster`.

What application do you recommend for such a case?

Answer (score 72):

### Hamster

Hamster helps you to keep track of how much time you spend on various
activities during the day. Whenever you move from one task to another, you can change your current activity, or you can record time spent afterwards.

Main app: hamster-time-tracker (Ubuntu 20.04 and later) hamster-applet (Ubuntu 18.04 and earlier)

To install hamster-time-tracker in Ubuntu 20.04 and later open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install hamster-time-tracker
```

Appindicator: hamster-indicator

To install hamster-indicator in Ubuntu 16.04 and earlier open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install hamster-indicator
```

I've grown fond of Hamster, and used it for tracking how long I worked on a Summer of Code project. It's added to your indicator menus (or systray). When you want to start/stop/change tasks, just hit <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and type what you are doing.

It makes some pretty nice statistics for you that can be exported as HTML, for sending to others. You can categorize parts of a job into groups to keep track of what exactly you're doing at the time.

Each task is labelled as *[task]@[job]*. For example, you could have *dev@project*, *doc@project*, etc. Hamster will do some auto-completion on these as well so most of the time you only need to type a few characters. Tags can be added to tasks as well for further categorization.

---

[image: Screenshot of Project Hamster by Toms Bauģis]
Screenshot by [Toms Bauģis](https://www.flickr.com/photos/toms/4332774392/)

Comment: thanks, can i have tracking of each job and it's parts separatly?

Comment: Yep! Each task is labeled as [task]@[job]. For example, you could have dev@project, doc@project, etc. Hamster will do some auto-completion on these as well so most of the time you only need to type a few characters. Tags can be added to tasks as well for further categorization.

Comment: Add your information to your answer, that way it doesn't get buried in comments. See here for more tips: http://meta.ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/257/i-am-an-existing-ubuntu-community-member-how-does-stackexchange-work

Comment: Can a link be provided, or what apt-get package it is?

Comment: I have tried Hamster and I think its amazing. So simple and productive. Only one issue, the indicator in Unity (12.04) doesn't stay on top after a reboot and I have to start the actual app again. Is there a way to make it appear next to the clock?

Comment: Hamster is good, but it does't track multiple activities for example charging my ipod and super secret project unless i create a single activity for both of them.

Comment: is it open source application or paid ?

Answer (score 26):

I use [gtimelog](http://mg.pov.lt/gtimelog).

Well.  I wrote gtimelog.  So it works for me.  YMMV.  I'm not the best software maintainer, I'm afraid.

[image: gtimelog 0.8 screenshot]

Comment: Looks great simple. I hope it's functionality do so. I'll give it a try. And well done to distribute it.

Answer (score 25):

Have you tried [toggl](http://www.toggl.com/)

Its an online app but it has a native linux client

[image: toggl linux client]

Comment: i tested it, it looks be great!

Comment: nice and easy to use

Comment: +1 for Toggl, especially because it has a web component and an Android app...

Comment: unfortunately [only 64bit binary package available for native client](http://support.toggl.com/toggl-on-my-desktop/) :(

Comment: This is my favorite too. I liked it so much that spent time writing a detailed review: http://pranas.net/toggl-review/

Comment: DON'T USE IT, IF YOU WANT PRIVACY. IT SELLS YOUR DATA.

Answer (score 19):

I recommend Emacs with [Org-Mode](http://orgmode.org/), installed by default together with emacs. Here is a screenshot of a Org-Mode buffer:

[image]

Why **Emacs + Org-Mode**? to avoid context switch, keeping you in the [flow state](http://www.devx.com/DevX/Article/11659)!!! Sounds a bit radical, right?, I know, but I realized that -- in practice!

When I give Org-Mode a chance I completely abandoned my old way of work and started keep me *more focus* on what really matter (code). My old workflow was:

- Stop code and go *mark as done* some items;
- Switch to the opened browser, looking for the [remember the milk](http://www.rememberthemilk.com/) opened TAB;
- Check my TODO tasks for that day and check OUT *done items*;
- go back to my editor;
- finally, restart the work (may take some more minutes to deeply focus again).

With Org-Mode, I just need to switch to the Org-Mode buffer, pressing `Ctrl + x b`, and mark items as DONE -- switching back to my previous buffer. No more browser (or external app) + editor.

I also would like to suggest to adopt [The Pomodoro Technique](http://www.pomodorotechnique.com/), a really simple technique to get the most out of time management. Its more simple then GTD and easy to use in Emacs + Org-Mode: Put a timer of 25 minutes in all your tasks and Org-Mode will alert you always a task end. Better then ever!

Comment: Can also use a physical egg timer for the pomodoro technique, which makes it hard to ignore!

Comment: This actually does not answer the question, how did it get that many votes? This is about task control, not time tracking.

Comment: @igorsantos07 org-mode also supports time tracking

Answer (score 14):

[arbtt](http://freshmeat.net/projects/arbtt) is an automatic rule based time tracker. It looks at the active window titles on your desktop and automatically logs the title. It can catagorize the titles based on how you configure it, and then it can report back stats.

So it might report back how much time is spent on a webdomain, in vim, and on facebook so you can look at your productivity.

Comment: It looks like it has been abandoned, unfortunately. Or it still works well?

Answer (score 13):

A good one that I have used in the past is [Klok](http://www.getklok.com/), an adobe air application.  It works great for tracking all your different projects, and giving you charts and graphs to break down how you're spending your time.  The free version only exports timesheets in MS Excel format -- they want you to buy the full version for html and xml export.

[image: Klock application]

Comment: thanks, i'm really excited to test it. i'm currently struggling with installing air on my amd64. +1 for shot.

Comment: Downovoted: Adobe Air no longer supports Linux.

Answer (score 7):

I'm surprised ActivityWatch isn't mentioned in any of these threads. Found it after a lot of searching online.

[Repository link with install instructions](https://github.com/ActivityWatch/activitywatch/)

It has exactly the features that I needed:

0. completely local data (no account signup needed)
1. application level time tracking (also website level time tracking if you install the browser extension)
2. idle time detection
3. categorization of applications into work/fun/etc.
4. tracks activity from the background, instead of me having to consciously log tasks/events

Would have probably bought it even if it was paid, but best part, it's completely open source! Plus, it's under active development, unlike other 2010 apps in this thread which are unmaintained 11 years later.

Answer (score 6):

Hamster is rather nice if you want one that's got a panel applet.  There is another one that is written in Java called jTimeSched.  This one has been useful on a thumb drive because I can run it on Windows, Mac and Linux, provided the host computer has Java installed. (It is available [here](http://kbase.dominik-geyer.de/apps%3ajtimesched) and is not in the repositories.)

Answer (score 5):

For all fans of Harvest (getharvest.com) i recommend simple gtk application:

https://github.com/tkowalewski/harvest-gtk

Answer (score 5):

KTimeTracker is a nice tool and is supported by Canonical.

Answer (score 4):

[Watson](http://tailordev.github.io/Watson/) is an open source command-line tool for time tracking. The code is [here on Github](https://github.com/TailorDev/Watson). It comes with an (optional) server-side backend called [crick](https://github.com/TailorDev/crick), which can collect the time tracking data of a team.

After looking around for quite a bit and only finding no longer working / no longer maintained / convoluted / commercial time tracking software for Linux, I found watson and settled for it. It has [well throught-through commands](http://tailordev.github.io/Watson/user-guide/commands/) so I don't really mind that it's "only" a command-line tool.

Answer (score 3):

If you access to a web server [Kimai](http://www.kimai.org) is a nice PHP/SQL web application. You configure different clients and for each of them different projects and also different tasks. Also it can be used by many users. The information can be exported to PDF, CSV and XLS.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I'd also recommend TSheets. It's simple to switch back and forth from your jobs to accurately account for the time spent on each project. I also like that it has a Who's Working widget where I can see who on my team is working on what project in real time.

http://www.tsheets.com/workforce-management.html#whos_working

Answer (score 2):

You may also try [Timedoctor.com](http://www.timedoctor.com).

That is what we use in our computers now running on different platforms. I was actually tasked to do research on the best time tracking software today and out of many referrals and suggestions “Time Doctor” is the only software which I could grade as “A”.

Comment: A great free alternative to TimeDoctor (that don't even explain what it does from the landing page, or how the Free package works, wtf) is [RescueTime](https://www.rescuetime.com/ref/1098140). There's a [descriptive answer on it in here as well](http://askubuntu.com/a/698281/9330)

Answer (score 2):

This might seem an overkill for the OP but it's really useful to deeply track your productivity: [RescueTime](https://www.rescuetime.com/ref/1098140).

It's supported on Linux (besides Mac/Windows). You install a small application that stays in your tray and it tracks all your windows, generating later a report on your productivity.
It can automatically categorize a LOT of applications, and for those he understands wrong or doesn't know, you can set what the window means: very productive, productive, neutral, distracting or very distracting. That sums up to a productivity score for your day. You can also ignore some applications that has no actual meaning and you spend very little time on (such as Nautilus/Caja).

There's a paid version that adds features such as offline time tracking (you can manually enter what you did, such as meetings or client calls, the app asks what you were doing when your computer was idle!!!!), Zapier integrations, even deeper statistics and other stuff I don't actually know because I didn't use the paid version after the trial :)

This was the only application that really helped me stay focused - because I was afraid of receiving that dreaded email by Sunday morning saying I was unproductive D:

[image: Dashboard]

Comment: Current pricing: Free 2 week trial. Then $6.50 a month as minimum.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Internet: [HarvestApp](http://www.getharvest.com/) is one the best tools out there. Thats is if you don't mind time tracking on a web-app.

**sidenote:** They have [free](https://signup.harvestapp.com/signup) trial accounts, too.

Comment: A great free alternative to HarvestApp that does not depend on manual input is [RescueTime](https://www.rescuetime.com/ref/1098140). There's a [descriptive answer on it in here as well](http://askubuntu.com/a/698281/9330)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [Fanurio](http://www.fanuriotimetracking.com/). It is working on multiple platforms including Ubuntu. After installing it **they will give a 14 days trial**. If you like it you can buy the software to unlock the unlimited edition.

Answer (score 1):

We use http://projectsputnik.com. It has amazing time tracking features plus great project management functionality. Additionally you can mark some of time entries as billable and see the ratio of billable hours to total worked hours.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, I would suggest Replicon [time clock software](http://www.replicon.com/time-clock) for time tracking.

Answer (score 1):

I  prefer Rachota. It is a jar file with a simple GUI. http://rachota.sourceforge.net/en/index.html

It stores time sheets in XML and there is some options for tracking teams etc. Just download it, place it in your favorite folder and run as java from command line or launcher icon

```
java -jar /...folders.../rachota.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

[TSheets time tracking software](http://www.tsheets.com) has exactly what you're looking for. You'll have the ability to list an unlimited number of jobs for each day and specifically account for the time on the tasks within each job code. Also, it's easy to generate reports that show the breakdown of each task and the project overall.

http://www.tsheets.com/overview-of-online-timesheet-software.php#multi_job_codes

Comment: Is it open source?

Answer (score 0):

[Talygen](http://www.talygen.com) is highly recommended for all those who love to track their time and activities. I've been using Talygen for a couple of months. It helps me track multiple projects.

Comment: I can't find the license info on the link provided. Doesn't look like open source. Can you provide some info about the license?

Answer (score 0):

For command-line tool I recommend [timew](https://timewarrior.net/reference/timew.1/), [watson](https://tailordev.github.io/Watson/) or [timetrap](https://github.com/samg/timetrap).