# TimeTracker app that logs programs

Tags: time, tracker, productivity, hamster

Does anyone know of a time tracker app that logs which program you are using. So, if I'm using LibreOffice it'll log me as working, but then when the focus switches back to chrome, it'll log me as "procrastinating"

Thanks!

(first question ftw!)

Comment: similar if not the same question?  http://askubuntu.com/questions/4113/which-time-tracker-application-do-you-recommend

Comment: Similar, but not the same. arbtt and Hamster might be the closest answeres. I suppose arbtt only logs, but doesn't count your working time. Hamster can do something similar with workspaces, but [there is a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hamster-applet/+bug/529687).

Comment: Another similar question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/7273/how-to-stay-productive-what-time-management-software-is-available

Comment: I want a program that tracks the focus of what I'm working on automatically.

I used rescuetime (http://www.rescuetime.com/) for a while but their unnoffical linux client (https://launchpad.net/rescuetime-linux-uploader) doesn't work very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had been using [Replicon’s time tracking](http://www.replicon.com/time-tracking-software.aspx) software which is an easy to use web application. It has a simple to use interface and great usability features which helps in easy project and time tracking and management for business projects.

Comment: This doesn't track program usage, so it's useless.

I used rescuetime (http://www.rescuetime.com/) for a while but their unnoffical linux client (https://launchpad.net/rescuetime-linux-uploader) doesn't work very well.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that [arbtt](https://arbtt.nomeata.de/), the **a**utomatic **r**ule **b**ased **t**ime **t**racker, is what you are looking for. The code is [here on Github](https://github.com/nomeata/arbtt).

Like you want it, the `arbtt-capture` daemon collects information about which window has been the active window for how long (while counting time without any action as "idle" once a configurable threshold is hit). You then use a second program `arbtt-stats` to analyze the collected data, providing statistics about how much time you spent on what.

(Source: [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/69064))

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck with [rescuetime.com](http://www.rescuetime.com/) under Ubuntu and Mac OSX for time tracking.  The free version will give you a 3 month window.

The customized goals have been fun to play with.  I made a goal of less than .1 minutes of "uncategorized" time to make sure that nearly everything is categorized somehow.